# How do I center my Google maps marker in tab with iframe

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got a problem to center my marker in tab with iframe

Example **[here](http://mau.my/cola-cola-edisi-terhad-tahun-1997-668552/)**, you click on Map tab and the marker is not centered. If direct link without iframe it looking great. You can see **[here](http://mau.my/maps.php?lat=3.190213&lng=101.5916&id=585)**.

```
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

The `center: myLatlng` looks like not working in tab with iframe. How do I fix this? Let me know

Comment: what browser are you using/testing? in safari 4 (mac) it is centered.

Comment: @jackJoe I'm on Win7 with Firefox4 / IE8

Comment: @Björn - yes chrome and opera centered, but not in Firefox and IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem once and I was able to solve it by triggering a resize event and setting the center again when the tab is clicked.

```
// add this to the tab click event
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Solve this with window resize

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
```